# Where are the MVVM Light snippets?

Tags: mvvm-light, code-snippets

It seems that snippets of MVVM Light are not installed when we use Nuget to install MVVM Light Toolkit.

Where can I find them ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Snippets are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight).

- Download the code (upper right *Clone or download* button) and extract it.
- Use the Visual Studio Code Snippet manager (from the "Tools" menu) to import the snippets located in the `Installer/InstallItems/Snippets/CSharp` folder of the extracted code.

Comment: Simply extract and put snippet files under \My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\MvvmLightCSharpSnippets . Then you can try it out by typing "mvvm". No restart is required.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who didn't find C# snippets in the download specified in the accepted answer, you can download MVVM Light extension

- for VS2015 (as well as for VS2013 and VS2012) from  [this link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee36692d-ed3f-4888-b904-281aaaeac529).
- for VS2017 from [this link.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentBugnion.MVVMLightforVS2017)

This not only installs C# snippets for you, but also the relevant Project and Item templates.

The download works with the Community Edition of VS2015 too.

Comment: Can be faster to download and easier. Thanks for posting. I updated the path of snippets in my answer as it changed since the first post.