# How to install MVVMLight snippets for VSE 2013 desktop

Tags: wpf, mvvm, nuget, mvvm-light, code-snippets

I have a Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop project. I have added MVVMLight via Nuget.

However, I don't have the MVVVMLight snippets installed such as "mvvminpc" etc....

How can I install the MVVMLight snippets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the MVVM Light snippets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708948/where-are-the-mvvm-light-snippets)

Comment: Is Resharper installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you are working using WPF, you may have installed just the libraries-only version, try to install the full package or download the VSIX file from CodePlex http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/downloads/get/763723.

**Update** :

MvvmLight code snippets do exist on Express editions of Visual Studio, but sometimes you may encounter some issues, here are the full [snippets](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Snippets/CSharp/) to download.

Comment: I have already done this. Perhaps the reason the snippets don't work is because I'm VS2013 Express Desktop version and not the full version?

Comment: I think MvvmLight Code snippets work just fine for VisualStudio Express editions like it's mentioned in this thread http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/discussions/256798, I will update my answer